# Windows Certification Kit - Bytecode generation error

Tags: javascript, windows, cordova, windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2017

I am writing an application in Angular 1.5.3, Ionic 1.3.3, and Cordova 6.5. I want to put my app on the Windows store and build for a Windows 10 phone. Most of my project code is written in ES5 and I have a few 3rd party libraries that are written in ES6 or Typescript but in my project I am just using the .min files.

These are the libraries:

- moment: https://github.com/moment/moment
- i18next: https://github.com/i18next/i18next
- ng-i18next: https://github.com/i18next/ng-i18next

If you look in those you will see that the libraries are written in Typescript and contain tsconfig.json files. In my project I am just using the .min files and it works great when I run the app.

Index.html:

```
  <script src="lib/i18next/i18next.min.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/ng-i18next/dist/ng-i18next.min.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/moment/min/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/moment-timezone/builds/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

These libraries keep on getting a bytecode error when I run the Windows Certification kit:

[image]

I don’t know what I can do to fix this. All the other certification tests pass.

Went through the 'how to fix steps':

1. I didn't build the app using F5. I used the Visual Studio 2017 -> store -> create a package for windows store
2. I don't know what that is
3. It's possible that the ES6 or Typescript files are not being seen as 'valid' but I don't know how to fix it
4. As I am just building on my local machine producing the build package, I'm not sure if there is anything to uninstall

Comment: Have you tried "How to fix" suggestions provided by failure report?

Comment: Please see edit.